# Dutch immigration at St Pancras intl

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, france, passport-stamps, eurostar

We are a family of 3 taking direct train from London St Pancras intl to Amsterdam which has started in April 2018. We have valid Schengen visa already and we hold Indian passports.

However I have a doubt about exit from UK and entry into Schengen. Will our passports be stamped accordingly  ?

Later from Amsterdam we are taking train to Paris and than flight to our home country.  Will it be a smooth immigration from Paris if our passports are not stamped inward at St Pancras intl ?

If someone who has taken this journey can clear our doubts. Thanks

Answer (score 27):

French border police are present at St. Pancras, and process all passengers embarking on Eurostar services.

French police is supposed to stamp passports except those of EU, EFTA, Andorran, Monaco and San Marino citizens, or persons holding article 10/20 residence cards.

However, they often ignore stamping low-risk passports (US, Canadian, Australian, NZ etc.), which is illegal on their part and can land the traveller in great trouble if exiting through a stricter country such as Sweden.

However, this isn't likely with an Indian passport.

Still, you **must** make sure they stamp your passport (insist if necessary), both on entry and exit.